# Primeng p-radioButton - text as anchor

Tags: typescript, radio-button, primeng

Is it possible to transform the text of a radio button to an anchor?

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/radiobutton

In this case, Option 1 could be a link that the user clicks to open a new browser window to view the page.

This will not work:

```
 <p-radioButton name="operation_group"  [(ngModel)]="modelcol" tabindex=2 inputId="opt1">
 <a href="https://www.thesitewizard.com/">Operation</a> </p-radioButton>
```

Comment: Why are you use radio button if you want to open a link on click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No css needed, just set label to empty string and add the anchor.

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to directly implement this in Primeng. But you need to do a trick for this. Might it would not be the best solution but it will serve your purpose. It is a workaround only.

Taking the example of Primeng Radio button.

I have added a custom class **customeRadio** in html and also added `<a>`tag in same as option value.

```
<div class="ui-g-12 customeRadio">
    <p-radioButton name="group1" value="Option 1" label="Option 1" [(ngModel)]="val1" inputId="opt1">
    </p-radioButton><a href="">Option 1</a>
  </div>
  <div class="ui-g-12 customeRadio">
    <p-radioButton name="group1" value="Option 2" label="Option 2" [(ngModel)]="val1" inputId="opt2">
    </p-radioButton><a href="">Option 2</a>
  </div>
  <div class="ui-g-12 customeRadio">
    <p-radioButton name="group1" value="Option 3" label="Option 3" [(ngModel)]="val1" inputId="opt3">
    </p-radioButton><a href="">Option 2</a>
  </div>
```

Now in styles.css file or where where you want to write the css for it.

Just hide the all label content using css selector property:

```
.customeRadio label{
    display:none;
}
```

That's all !